# .Net 6 API not returning nested list objects

Tags: json, .net, api, .net-6.0

We are moving our APIs from .net 4.8 library to .Net 6. I cam across a weird problem where none of the nested objects (Costs) are being serialized.

I have tried adding the using in the startup but my apis dont work with this option on. I cant even see the controllers being hit with this options on.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
...............

    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

OR

```
`services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>`
`{`
`options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();`
`options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;`
`});`

        


services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(o =>
{
    o.JsonSerializerOptions.MaxDepth = 4;
    o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    o.JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = null;
});
```

What Am I missing?

I expect the format below

```
   `{
       "Status": 200,
       "Message": "Processed Successfully",
       "Description": null,
       "Errors": null,
       "ResponseObject": {
       "Costs": [
        {
            "Component": "xxx",
            "Key1": "123",
            "Key2": null,
            "Key3": null,
            "ProductCode": "x",
            "From": "2021-08-05T00:00:00",
            "To": "2021-08-05T23:59:59",
            "Value": "1584",
            "CurrencyCode": null,
            "UnitOfMeasure": null
        },
        {
            "Component": "X",
            "Key1": "123",
            "Key2": null,
            "Key3": null,
            "ProductCode": "Y",
            "From": "2021-08-05T00:00:00",
            "To": "2021-08-05T23:59:59",
            "Value": "3131",
            "CurrencyCode": null,
            "UnitOfMeasure": null
        }
        ]
    }`
```

The C# object is as below:

```
public class Response 
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public object Errors { get; set; }
    public object ResponseObject { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the code used to populate the object:

```
var costsVM = new CostsVM();

var response = new Response();
costsVM.Costs.AddRange(costs);
response.ResponseObject = costsVM;
response.Status = 200;
response.Message = "Processed Successfully";
response.Description = null;
return Ok(response);
```

Cost VM is defined as below:

```
  public class CostsVM
    {
        public List<CostsDTO> Costs = new List<CostsDTO>();
    }

public class CostsDTO
{
    public string Component { get; set; }
    public string? Key1 { get; set; }
    public string? Key2 { get; set; }
    public string? Key3 { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    public DateTime To { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string? CurrencyCode { get; set; }
    public string? UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you understand a difference between deserialize and serialize? What do you have json or c# object ? "I expect the format below" but what do you have? and what is an original object?

Comment: Yes I understand the difference. Thanks. I have a c# object which I expect to serialize to json like the above format.

Comment: I don think that anybody can help you ,  unleess you  post the classes and  code that created the object and code you were using trying to serialize. Enough just one typo in a property name and nothing can be serialized.

Comment: Yes I understand the difference. Thanks. I have a c# object which I expect to serialize to json like the above format. My object looks like below:

public class Response 
    {
        public bool Success { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
         
        public object ResponseObject { get; set; }
    }
The responseObject gets assigned a list of objects (costs in this case) for every different API. For some reason ResponseObjetc is not being serialised. Thanks

Comment: @Serge I have updated my original post to also include the c# object now. Hope that helps?

Comment: there is no Costs object in the class you show do why would you expect there to be in the JSON?

Comment: @sagg I think you have to post the code that was used to create the object before serialization. I can not see anything about Cost class in your Response class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I seem to have found the fix for it.

I needed to enable IncludeFields in JsonSerializer

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
     options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
     options.JsonSerializerOptions.MaxDepth = 64;
     options.JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true;
 });
```